# R: Issues with Nelder-mead optimization

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimize a self-written function using the fminbnd (neldermead package) function in R. I get the following error message:

`Error in if (fr < fhigh) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I've set verbose to true to try and identify the issue, here is the output directly preceeding the error message

```
Step #1 : order 
================================================================= 
Iteration #1 (total = 1) 
Function Eval #2 
Xopt: [0.04] 
Fopt: 1.100429e+02 
DeltaFv: Inf 
Center: [2.85944413880818] 
Size: 5.638888e+00 
Vertex #1/2 : fv=1.100429e+02, x=4.000000e-02
 
Vertex #2/2 : fv=Inf, x=5.678888e+00
 
Reflect 
xbar=[0.04] 
boxlinesearch 
> xhigh=[5.67888827761635], fhigh=Inf 
> xbar=[0.04] 
> xr = [-7.29055476090126] 
Function Evaluation #3 at [-7.29055476090126  ]
```

I believe the issue occurs because DeltaFv/fhigh goes to Infinity, before that they are a number and don't produce an issue.

Here is the function I am trying to optimize:

```
softmaxEV <- function(startphi){
  pL <- c()
  for (row in 1:nrow(oneDat)){
    VA= oneDat[row, "EVA"]
    VB= oneDat[row, "EVB"]
    
    if (oneDat[row, "response"] == 0){
      p= exp(startphi*VA)/(exp(startphi*VA)+exp(startphi*VB))
      pL <-append(pL,p)
    }
    else {
      p= 1- (exp(startphi*VA)/(exp(startphi*VA)+exp(startphi*VB)))
      pL <-append(pL,p)
    }
  }
  gEV <- -2*sum(log(pL))
  return(gEV)
}
```

Based on the choice made in a binary choice trial it calculates the probability that option A was chosen based on a given decision strategy, and at the end calculates the goodness of fit for this choice strategy.

Here's the code I use for the optimization, it's embedded in a for loop that loops over participants (thus assigning the 'oneDat' dataframe needed for the function). I've set a bound between 0 and 10.

```
optRes <- fminbnd(softmaxEV, startphi,0,10, verbose= TRUE)
```

To play around with it I've tried removing the bounds and use fminsearch instead, but I still get the same error. I've also changed the bounds and still get the same error. Ultimately, I do need the bounds to be in place.
I thought maybe my function was the issue but I tried many different 'startphis' for it and it never throws and error or impossible numbers. I've tried going into the source code of the function but am not advanced enough in coding to be able to understand it and the many functions on which it calls.

I also tried the fminbnd function from the 'pracma' package but it also does not work.

(I've also translated the code to python and used the minimize() function and still get the same error over there as well)

If anyone has any idea why this might be happening I would love to hear about it, thanks!

Comment: Try using an alternate form for your quotients of exponentials, e.g., the first suggested by Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-%28exp%28a%29%2F%28exp%28a%29+%2B+exp%28b%29%29%29

Comment: @Roland's suggestion is worth trying.  You are calculating things like `log(exp(a)/(exp(a) + exp(b)))`, and that's very likely to overflow for extreme values of `a` and `b`.  It looks as though you only have one parameter that you are optimizing, so there are many other choices of optimizer besides the ones in `neldermead`:  I'd suggest `stats::optimize`.  Others are `stats::optim` and `optimx::optimx` if you actually have multiple parameters.  Both of the latter two offer Nelder-Mead optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know exactly what is happening without an example `oneDat` `data.frame`. However, `softmaxEV` could be made much more efficient and numerically stable. Using @Roland's suggestion:

```
VAB <- with(oneDat, (EVA - EVB)*sign(response - 0.5))
softmaxEV2 <- function(phi) 2*colSums(log1p(exp(outer(VAB, phi))))
```

Compare this to the original:

```
all.equal(Vectorize(softmaxEV)(-5:5), softmaxEV2(-5:5))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Data:

```
set.seed(1938304396)
oneDat <- data.frame(
  EVA = runif(10),
  EVB = runif(10),
  response = sample(0:1, 10, 1)
)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! I've tried out the alternate specification for the exponentials in the softmax function and for most of the dataset this results in equal outcomes compared to the original. However, for some it changes, but I think that may be the point? Where the original softmax function goes to infinity, the alternate version outputs a number, but I wanted to make sure that this is intended?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. The original formulation is numerically unstable. For example, if both `startphi*VA` and `startphi*VB` were large-ish negative numbers, the original would divide by zero, but the updated version would calculate without loss of precision because we are exponentiating `(EVA - EVB)*phi`.